# How to transform with state?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to build a Kafka streams application using the new version of the  DSL (v1.0) but I don't see how to configure a stateful stream transformation. A basic but complete example of how to achieve this would be very helpful.

I didn't find any (stateful) transform examples in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/1.0/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples). According to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-) the following strategy should be followed:

```
 StateStoreSupplier myStore = Stores.create("myTransformState")
 .withKeys(...)
 .withValues(...)
 .persistent() // optional
 .build();

 builder.addStore(myStore);

 KStream outputStream = inputStream.transform(new TransformerSupplier() { ... }, "myTransformState");
```

However, it's not clear what the type of `builder` should be in the example, none of `Topology` or `StreamsBuilder` has a method `addStore`. If I try `addStateStore` instead it only accepts an argument of type `StoreBuilder` which is not the type of `myStore` defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As JavaDocs explain, `Stores#create` is deprecated in 1.0.0:

> @deprecated use persistentKeyValueStore(String), persistentWindowStore(String, long, int, long, boolean), persistentSessionStore(String, long), lruMap(String, int). or inMemoryKeyValueStore(String)

Thus, in your case you would create a persistent key-value store supplier via `Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("myTransformState")`

In a second step, you need to create a StoreBuilder via `Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(...)` that takes you previously created store supplier as argument.

Afterwards, you can add the `StoreBuilder` to your builder

```
StreamsBuilder#addStateStore(final StoreBuilder builder)
```

To connect the store to your transformer you just provide the store name as additional argument as before.